# Integrating absolute value in a mgf

Tags: calculus, probability

For this question, I am trying to find the mgf of a random variable having pdf:

$$f_X(x)=e^{-2|x|}I_{(-\infty, \infty)}(x)$$

I know that you have to integrate the function multiplied by $e^{tX}$ over its support. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to integrate the absolute value of x.

I was thinking that you could do two times the integral from $0$ to $+\infty$ rather than integrating from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Is this the correct way of going about doing this?

Comment: yes, you can use this approach when function graph is symmetric with respect to axis $y$

Comment: And in general when you are dealing with the piecewise function like this, you can always try to split the range first